# Simply supported beam with a truss

Tags: beam, aerospace-engineering

i am trying to find out the best way to approach a design task for a plane wing with a truss support. i am treating the wing as a simply supported beam but i have no idea how to incorporate the truss except as and extra support but i don't know whether this is suitable.

i am assuming it can be done via truss and member methods, this is the layout i am attempting

[image]

Comment: So, will that truss be in tension or compression?

Comment: Your wing without the strut, would be a cantilevered beam not a simply supported beam.   A simply supported beam, in my books implies a pin connection at one end and a roller connection at the other.  What you are showing here and with what little I know about airframes, is more likely to be a fixed connection of the wing to the fuselage.  I would guess that the strut to fuselage would also be fixed but could also be pinned.  Same goes for your strut to wing connection.  I highly suspect your wing would be considered a continuous beam over your strut connection.

Comment: the truss would be in compression, the beam could be cantilever or i could treat it as an overhang, its more whether the truss would effect the suport differently if i just treated the connection from it to the beam as a fixed support, also working out the reactions on the support its self

Comment: This is a simple static problem but it seems you don't know the fundamentals. I suggest hiring an engineer to help you to find the best support scenario, or ask your TA at school if you are a student.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your wing can be assumed roughly as a two-span continuous beam supported from left by pin support (or fixed support but more on that later), then by other pin support by the diagonal tension strut, and the last right part as a cantilever beam.

Assuming the distributed load of W upward
WE have the maximum moment above the strut at the middle of the beam

$$M_{L2}=-WL_2^2/$$

$$M_{L1}= -WL_1^2/8+1/2M_{L2}$$
And the tensin in strut is

$$T=sec( a )*(1/2 \ W*L1+W*L2)$$

'

[image: wing]